# Why does the GCD of two ideals exist?

Tags: abstract-algebra, algebraic-number-theory

I've been trying to wrap my head around this and I feel like I'm getting stuck in circular logic.

The definition I'm using is the gcd of ideals $I_1, I_2$ of a ring $R$ is an ideal $J$ of $R$ such that $I_1 \subseteq J$ and $I_2 \subseteq J$.

Furthermore if $J'$ is any other ideal such that $I_1 \subseteq J'$ and $I_2 \subseteq J'$ then $J \subseteq J'$

If it helps I'm working in a Dedekind domain.

Okay so trivially there exists an ideal that contains $I_1, I_2$ that is the entire ring, so we know they have a common divisor.

Let $\gcd(I_1,I_2)=J$. It is clear that $J=I_1+I_2$ since if not, there exists $x\in J, x\notin I_1, I_2$. But we have $I_1, I_2 \subseteq I_1+I_2$ and $I_1+I_2\subset J$ and thus $J$ would not be the $\gcd$. Hence $\gcd(I_1,I_2)=I_1+I_2$.

Is there a better way to phrase this? I feel like I'm using the assumption there is a gcd to prove there is a gcd.

Comment: Why would $J\ne I_1+I_2$ imply there exists $x\in J$ but $x\not\in I_1,I_2$? (And that's not even contradictory; the ideal $I_1+I_2$ *does*, in general, have elements that are not in $I_1$ or $I_2$.) What would the existence of such an $x$ have to do with the rest of that paragraph?

Comment: First show the gcd, if it exists, is unique. Then show $I_1+I_2$ satisfies the defining property of the gcd.

Comment: So let's say the gcd exists. Then $gcd(I_1,I_2)=J$, then $I_1,I_2\subseteq J$. Suppose that also $gcd(I_1,I_2)=J'$. Then also $I_1,I_2\subseteq J'$. But by our definition of gcd, this means that $J\subseteq J'$ and $J'\subseteq J$. Hence $J=J'$ and the gcd is unique.

Now we consider $I_1+I_2$. $I_1,I_2\subseteq I_1+I_2$. Let $J$ be any ideal of $R$ such that $I_1,I_2\subseteq J$. Since $I_1,I_2\subseteq J$, elements of the form $a+b, a\in I_1, b\in I_2$ are in $J$. Hence $I_1+I_2 \subseteq J$. And that is what it means to be the gcd.

Comment: I think that's right.

Answer (score 1):

Let $K$ be the intersection of all ideals of $R$ which contain both $I_1$ and $I_2.$ Then $K$ is an ideal since *any* intersection of ideals is an ideal. [I'm assuming you're working with 2-sided ideals.]

This $K$ contains $I_1$ and $I_2,$ and if $J'$ is any ideal of $R$ containing each of $I_1$ and $I_2,$ then $K \subset J',$ since by definition $K$ is the intersection of *all* ideals of $R$ which contain each of $I_1$ and $I_2,$ and so must be a subset of $J'.$

So there is indeed a gcd for the two ideals, and that may coincide with your description, I just wanted to show how to see a gcd *exists,* even not knowing a description of it.

Comment: Would u plz help me understanding $I_1,I_2\subseteq I_1+I_2$? for example,how  $I_1$ is an element of $ I_1+I_2$?  To me  $ I_1+I_2$ has nothing common with $I_1$ .

Comment: @Andrew My answer didn't claim the statement implied by the first part of your comment. [Also $I_1$ is not a single element but is a set of elements, so in partitular is not an element of $I_1+I_2.$